# Flink Streaming - How can I create a window based on first (by event timestamp) keyed event

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am using Flink's DataStream API in order to work on keyed stream with tumbling windows.

The simplified problem is as follows:

Input event objects example:

```
{timestamp:1462363362000, user_id:1, country:US, mark:50}
{timestamp:1462363361000, user_id:1, country:US, mark:40}
{timestamp:1462363368000, user_id:1, country:US, mark:30}
{timestamp:1462363368000, user_id:2, country:US, mark:200}
{timestamp:1462363367000, user_id:2, country:US, mark:300}
```

1. I used assignTimestampsAndWatermarks for using events timestamp
2. I keyed the data using the user_id field

.

```
KeyedStream<Event, Tuple> keyedStream = eventsStream
.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new MessageTimestampExtractor())
.keyBy("user_id");
```

Now that I have the keyed data I would like to have 10 minute windows based on the earliest event by event's timestamp and later on perform some kind of aggregation on that window.

How can I create windows with a static size (10 minute) that will start according to the first for that user_id on that window, meaning that when window is over and a user_id will be seen again a new window will be created.

The only thing that I found that is answering a similar requirement (but not exactly the one that I need) is using Event-time Session windows (Not stable on the moment of writing this question, Flink 1.1 - https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/apis/streaming/windows.html)

Any idea how it can be achieved?

Thanks

Comment: What are you missing from the event time session window?

Comment: Using event time session window will not trigger the window in case of a pre configured delta between the first event of the window and the "current time", it is by the last event delta. @rmetzger

Comment: I think you have to implement your own trigger, based on the session window one.

Comment: @OrGuz did you find a solution to this?